# ArgumentOutOfRangeExecption by a Insert

Tags: c#, wpf

Hey stackoverflow user,

The lista.Instert(...) has a problem with the declaration.

The Main task of this Project is that i can add by clicking on a button 2 columns in the Listview... I got the basic structure but somehow he is always giving me the  ArgumentOutOfRangeExecption error... I reduced all other parts and just include the main function. I hope this can lead someone to solve the Stupid problem....

XML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="169,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <ListView  Margin="10,58,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxWidth="600" VerticalAlignment="Top"  ItemsSource="{Binding lista}" AlternationCount="{Binding lista.Count}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Width="40" Text="{Binding Hexnumber_op_Code}" />
                    <TextBlock Width="40" Text="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Width="40" Text="{Binding OP_Code}" Background="{Binding Background_OP_Code}"/>

                    <Button Width="40" Content="+" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.Cmd}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow:

```
namespace WpfApplication5
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Lista> lista { get; set; }
    private RelayCommand cmd;


    public RelayCommand Cmd
    {
        get { return cmd ?? (cmd = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(AddRow))); }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        lista = new ObservableCollection<Lista> {};


        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

    }
    public void AddRow(object obj)
    {
        int numer;
        Int32.TryParse(obj.ToString(), out numer);
       lista.Insert(numer, new Lista()
        {  hexnumber_op_Code = "10",OP_Code = "1",});

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lista.Insert(10, new Lista() { Hexnumber_op_Code = "1D", Background_OP_Code = "hallo", OP_Code = "red" });
        lista.Insert(20, new Lista() { Hexnumber_op_Code = "1D", Background_OP_Code = "hallo", OP_Code = "red" });
    }

    public class Lista
    {

        public string hexnumber_op_Code;

        public string Hexnumber_op_Code
        {
            get { return this.hexnumber_op_Code; }
            set
            {
                this.hexnumber_op_Code = value;
                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Hexnumber_op_Code"));
                }
            }
        }


        public string background_OP_Code;
        public string Background_OP_Code
        {
            get
            {

                if (background_OP_Code == null)
                {
                    return background_OP_Code = "White";
                }
                else
                    return this.background_OP_Code;
            }
            set
            {
                this.background_OP_Code = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Background_OP_Code");
            }
        }
        public string oP_Code;
        public string OP_Code
        {
            get { return this.oP_Code; }
            set
            {
                this.oP_Code = value;
                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("OP_Code"));
                }
            }
        }


        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }


    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        #endregion

        #region ICommand Members


        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @Grant Winney The Button_Click() throws the problem.

Comment: try-  lista.add( new Lista() { Hexnumber_op_Code = "1D", Background_OP_Code = "hallo", OP_Code = "red" });

Comment: @lacura because you are attempting to insert an item at location `10` and also at location `20`...I'm suspecting your collection doesn't have either a place to put that item (thus, `ArgumentOutOfRange`)

Comment: Because i´m just stupid... i changed the values to 1,2 and all is sown...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lista.Add(new Lista() { Hexnumber_op_Code = "1D", Background_OP_Code = "hallo", OP_Code = "red" });
    lista.Add(new Lista() { Hexnumber_op_Code = "1D", Background_OP_Code = "hallo", OP_Code = "red" });
}
```

Quoting from MSDN [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132411%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ]

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException   :  index is less than zero.
>   -or- index is greater than Count.

Where Count : Number of elements actually contained in the Collection.

So when you try to insert at 10 and 20, your current index is greater than count.